# How to apply If Else on Textview on button click without using any Integer variable?

Tags: java, android

Is there logic that we apply if else on Text of TextView without using integer?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text=findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button=findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (text!=Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)
                {
                    text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
                else
                {
                    text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | ~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
            }
        }
        );

    }
}
```

I want to do that, on button click, if the text is normal it will become Strikethrough and if the text is Strikethrough it will become normal.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `!=` to compare the `TextView`s?

Comment: Yeah there was some little bit mistake in logic, now i correct it, but i want to do the same thing without using any integer value...
do u have any other logic to compare TextView rather than == ???

Comment: Please see: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) (this actually applies to all non-primitives in Java)

Comment: I appreciate your link, but can u plz do correction in my IF ELSE statement in my code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to toggle it, try

```
text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() ^  Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

No if needed.